# How to rebuild profile picture widget on changes to file in Firebase Storage (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to build a profile picture widget in Flutter that allows the user to upload an image to Firebase storage and retrieve that image once it has been uploaded. My problem is that I call the _getImage() Function in initState() so anytime the user uploads a new photo the widget isn't rebuilt with the new photo unless the app is restarted. Is there a 'stream' like method I can use to listen to changes in a Firebase Storage location and rebuild a widget accordingly?

I use ImagePicker to get my image from gallery.

```
_pickImage() async {
final selected = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  _imageFile = File(selected.path);
});
_uploadFile(_imageFile);}
```

After the photo is chosen, it is uploaded to Firebase Storage.

```
_uploadFile(File _imageFile) async{
  var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  var storageRef = _storage.ref().child('user/profile/${user.uid}');
  var uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
}
```

Then to retrieve the image, I call the _getImage() function in initState().

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _getImage();
```

}

the _getImage() funtion.

```
_getImage() async {
var user  = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
var photoReference = _storage.ref().child("user/profile/${user.uid}");
photoReference.getData(1000000000).then((data){
  this.setState(() {
    imageFile = data;
  });
}).catchError((onError){
  print('error');
}); }
```

Comment: This is not the right way to use Firebase Storage. You should save the generated link of the uploaded image to the Cloud Firestore database. Then it will change realtime.

Comment: ah ok. My first thought was to create a collection in Firestore and save the download urls of each profile image inside but then I figured if I can pull the Image directly from Storage why use Firestore as a middleman. But If the best way to retrieve images and rebuild their widets is to use Firestore I shall do that.

Answer (score 0):

here is a example

```
final image = await ImagePicker()
                  

.pickImage(source:  ImageSource.gallery);

                  if (image == null) return;
              FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
              Reference ref = storage.ref().child("images/${DateTime.now()}");
              UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(File(image.path));
              uploadTask.then((res) async {
              String fileurl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
              return fileurl;
```

You have to upload image on firebase then retrieve the image url
then you can call it on user profile